# Apollo client fetchPolicy issues - query called twice

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

I'm using @apollo/client 3.2.0 with react. I have a component that retrieves the data using the useQuery hook. The query looks similar to this one:

```
query getChartData($year: Int!, $type: String!) {
  first_series_data(kpi: "SOME_KPI", year: $year, orderBy: "week", type: $type) {
    edges {
      node {
        value
        week
      }
    }
  }
  second_series_data(kpi: "SOME_KPI", year: $year, type: $type) {
    edges {
      node {
        date
        value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see in the query, I have two variables: **year** and **type**. Both are passed as props in the component and this component is rendered twice in the same view, with a different type prop.

**The problem** that I have is related to the **fetchPolicy** option. If I'm using one of `cache-and-network` or `network-only` fetch policies, one of the queries is called twice. This doesn't happen when I use `no-cache`. So I think it's a cache conflict, because the queries are similar, but I'm not sure and I don't know how to fix this.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? I’m having the same issue...

Comment: Nope, I had to change my views and queries to avoid this, but it's still happening sometimes. I also opened this ticket which is related, maybe something from there can help you: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/7436

Answer (score 1):

this issue is “fixed” in 3.4 :https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/7436

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWRqu.png)